# Одинаковые строки не равны PHP

Tags: php, curl, md5

Основная задача брать данные из robots.txt с сайта и сравнивать с моим robots.txt через md5(). Но проблема в том, что я специально скопировал с сайта robots.txt и вставил в свой robots.txt, строки получается абсолютно одинаковы, одинаковы типы, да все одинаково, но они не равны и мне прилетает false, если я их сравниваю.

Сравнивал если что не только через md5(), они всегда не равны, хотя полностью одинаковы.
trim() тоже использовал

Из файла domains-to-check берутся url

```
$file = file('domains-to-check.txt');

$robots = file_get_contents('robots.txt');

foreach ($file as $url) {

$ch = curl_init($url.'/robots.txt');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

if (md5($robots) == md5($data)){
    echo 'equal';
} else {
    echo 'no equal';
}    

var_dump($robots);
var_dump($data);

curl_close($ch);

}
```

Comment: Значит они на самом деле не одинаковы, просто вы разницу не заметили

Comment: ну тык помогите пожалуйста мне эту разницу найти, может там какая-нибудь кодировка разная или типо того, я хз че мне делать, я столько перепробовал

Comment: Хэш суммы реагируют на все изменения в файлах. Проверьте пробелы. Если они всё равно не равны - возможно дело в CRLF и LF окончаниях строк файлов(если работаете в Windows, то, скорее всего, в этом и проблема). Вы можете поменять окончания в vscode. Также можете скопировать файлы полностью, выполнив `cat web_robots.txt > my_robots.txt` в терминале(или PS/PWSH, если работаете в Windows)

Comment: у винды (у меня) были траблы с скачиванием, файлов, какогото фига менялась хэшсумма, разбираться было лень,- исспользовал для скачивания downloadmaster, он качал с корректной хэшсуммой

Comment: Да!!! проблема была в CRLF и LF окончаниях!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$replaced1 = str_replace (["\r\n", "\n", "\r"], '', $robots);
$replaced2 = str_replace (["\r\n", "\n", "\r"], '', $data);
```

Добавил эти строчки и теперь равны